# Is there any way to have multiple audio recorders at the same time?

Tags: android, audio-recording

I'm trying to use multiple audio recorders at the same time.

I tried different usage of AudioRecord and MediaRecorder, also tried visualizer which then I realized can not be used for Mic. I've read so many related questions here but still nothing helped me do it.

from what I've read in StackOverFlow I learned that it could be related to physical compatibility so I created this small app which would try to record audio from two different threads using MediaRecorder and tested it on different android devices. A few types of samsung, htc, lg, huawei and even some not-so-popular chinese devices. the only device that let two recorders work at the same time was a phone named "Macoox MC-X9". I made sure my app was working OK and the result was really what it should've been.

This is a sample of the recording thread:

```
private void startRecording(final MediaRecorder mRecorder, final int which){
    Log.d(TAG, "Record started : " + which);
    try {
        //mRecorder = new MediaRecorder(); //it's done somewhere else
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mRecorder.setMaxDuration(60 * 1000);

        mRecorder.setOnErrorListener(new MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onError(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
                stopRecording(mRecorder, which);
            }
        });

        mRecorder.setOnInfoListener(new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
                if (what == mr.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED) {
                    stopRecording(mRecorder, which);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Max duration reached !");
                }
            }
        });

        String mFileName = which + "_" + getTime() + mFileExt;
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(recDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + mFileName);
        mRecorder.prepare();
        mRecorder.start();
        makeToast("Record started : " + which);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
        makeToast("Error");
        stopRecording(mRecorder, which);
    }
}
```

Now I have a question, Is it possible to change other devices' compatibility in any way? I mean for example I can simply root a Samsung device and edit anything related if needed. I just want to be able to enable this option by any means necessary.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Not sure, but I think this depends on the hardware.

Comment: I'd really be happy if someone could name another phone which has this ability and is more popular than the one I mentioned. Doesn't matter how much it costs ;)

Comment: why you want to do this? the two files will contains almost the same content!

Comment: @suitianshi, I know that. I want to be able to create a visualizer when recording.

Comment: Should I really leave this question unanswered ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for depends strongly on the Hardware and drivers of the phone. So you are going to have a hard time in tampering with that.

Have you thought about recording one Audio File and opening it multiple times? Sounds like the best solution to me.

Comment: Actually I've tried that. but using visualizer needs the file to be played loudly and it's against recording regulation.